# pointer to function call vs pointer to member function call

Tags: c++, pointers

I always wondered why there is a stylistic difference between calling a pointer to function vs calling a pointer to a member function in terms of using the de-referencing operator `*`, i.e.

```
void(*fptr)()=&f; // pointer to function f()
fptr(); // call f() via pointer to function

Foo foo; // instance of Foo
void (Foo::*fptr)()=&Foo::f; // pointer to member function f()
(foo.*fptr)(); // call foo.f() via pointer to member function
```

In the first part, you don't use the `*` operator to call `f()` via the function pointer, but then one must use it in calling the member function via the pointer, `(foo.*fptr)()`. Why this difference? Why not just use `(foo.fptr)()` for consistency? Is there any profound reason or just this is the way C++ was designed?

Comment: Presumably you mean `foo.*fptr`?

Comment: You don't use the `*` operator in the second, either. You use `.*`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Well the compiler can emit an error in that case... Is this the reason? Yes, typo, edited it.

Comment: Well, what if `foo` already has a member called `fptr`?

Comment: There are special operators to dereference member function pointers: `.*` and `->*`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I understand this, I was wondering what was the reason for this differentiation. A reason was pointed out by Oli, however the compiler can be made to emit an error in that case. I was just wondering if this is the only reason why this differentiation happens. In a sense the pointer to member is almost like something belonging to the class so avoiding a name clash would make sense...

Comment: @vsoftco: What do you mean "the compiler can be made to emit an error"? What if `foo` has a member `fptr` and yet you still have a member function pointer in a variable named `fptr` and you want to invoke it on `foo`?

Comment: If you want consistency, you can always invoke the regular function pointer as `(*fptr)();`

Comment: @Jon, can just get an error like 'nameclash' or something. As I said, in a sense a pointer to a member is almost like a member of the class, so this will make sense.

Comment: @vsoftco: Uh... and getting an arbitrary error like that is good because? Sorry, but I completely disagree that it would make sense. You are proposing that me, an outside user of a class, may or may not get an error just because of how the author of the class decided to name its members. My code that compiles today may fail to compile tomorrow if the author adds a new private member named `fptr`.

Comment: @vsoftco No, it doesn't make sense. So you'd prevent the member function `fptr()` from being called just because someone happened to declare a pointer to member function of the same name? A pointer to member function is not a member of the class. It is a function pointer that has special requirements for its first argument. This requirement is met by having the `.*` and `->*` operators to deal with them.

Comment: @Jon, was saying that it would make sense from a consistency point of view, i.e. pointer to functions and pointer to member functions are called using similar syntax.

Comment: @Praetorian I see now, my proposal is actually creating a whole lot of trouble :) Thanks all for the comments!

Comment: @vsoftco: Even if I felt that the current setup is inconsistent, which I do not, a cure that is worse than the disease is no cure.

Comment: @Jon, yes I agree now that I understand better the issues one gets :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be quoting stuff from [C++ Common Knowledge](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321321928). The related chapter is titled **Pointers to member functions are not pointers**. There the author explains why **pointers to member functions cannot be implemented as pointer to functions**. I'll be using this (the fact that they're different things) as a justification for the different syntax :

> When you take the address of a non-static member function, you don't get an address; you get a pointer to member function.
>
> (...)
>
> As with a pointer to data member, we need an object or pointer to an object in order to dereference a pointer to member function. (...) In the case of a pointer to member function, we need the object's address to use as (or to calculate) the value of the `this` pointer for the function call and possibly for other reasons as well.
>
> Note that there is no such thing as a "virtual" pointer to member function. Virtualness is a property of the member function itself, not the pointer that refers to it.
>
> **This is one reason why a pointer to member function cannot be implemented, in general, as a simple pointer to function**. The implementation of the pointer to member function must store within itself information as to whether the member function to which it refers is **virtual** or **nonvirtual**, information about **where to find the appropriate virtual function table pointer**, an **offset** to be added to or subtracted from the function's `this` pointer and possibly other information. A pointer to member function is **commonly implemented as a small structure that contains this information**, although many other implementations are also in use.
>
> **Dereferencing and calling a pointer to member function usually involves examining the stored information and conditionally executing the appropriate virtual or nonvirtual function calling sequence**.

IMHO considering these differences one can justify the syntax difference, although historic design choices could have played their role.

Comment: thanks for the effort in writing the answer, +1, I was aware of these differences, my question was just about the style, but from all the answers/comments I now understand it makes more sense to have it as it is. My initial thought was that somehow the pointers to member functions are more "natural" to have a stronger relationship with the class than with the outer namespace, so in a sense can be treated like a member.

Answer (score 0):

If we simply use foo.fptr, it is the same as how we call a member function, making the compiler complex. Actually, fptr is not a member function of foo. Thus *fptr shows the difference. Maybe the compile can make that happen ,and I think that's how C++ was designed now.